# Trying to determine if Lable.new is used on a candle ....and what attributes the label may have

Tags: label, candlestick-chart

I am trying to figure out if there is anyway (within pine-script itself) to determine if a candle has a label on it?  ...and if so, what attributes are on the label? Maybe the label has a color on it or is pointed in a downward direction.  Does anyone know if this is even possible?

I haven't tried anything yet. I'm starting from scratch.